# Unity Procedural Build/Exe Creation

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, build-process

I want to export ingame items to seperate data files. Those files should also be "openable" to display information about the item. My idea is to create every item as an .exe that will open a small windowed unity app with and image and some texts/tabs.

How would I handle this "procedural building of .exes" from within another application? For exeample I have a game with an inventory. And when I press "export to file", the item is build to an "item data exe file", that is then portable and openable as a standalone "item previewer".

Thank you for help. For the start a general assessment of this idea could also be helpful.

Comment: If the goal is that your players are able to export items, without installing the Unity editor, then you should give up on the idea of each item being a small Unity app. Generating a Unity app requires the editor software, and it would violate the EULA to bundle that software into a new program that you distribute independently. You could however install a viewer app alongside your game, and associate it with the file extension of your item types, so when the player double-clicks an item the OS launches the viewer app to inspect it - much like opening an image viewer to view a jpeg.

Comment: Yes you might be right. The second viewer app might be the best possible solution. Or maybe you could build 1 exe in "readable textform/xml" and then create an item just by inserting/changing out the item data then just saving the string as exe. But I guess there is no way to create an "textform/xml" exe!?